# Easy math system but lot of errors

Tags: math-mode, luatex, build-system

I'm trying to do an easy system, but I received a lot of errors.

```
\[ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x  & \quad \text{if x > 0\\
0  & \quad \text{else}
\end{cases}
\]
```

Probably I'm doing something wrong and I receive a lot of errors, in particular for the use of &.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: A single mistake can generate a lot of errors. Dunno why but as a programmer I face this all the time.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can test as it is. From code fragment follows, that there is missing `}` after `\text{...` .This error is not related to `LuaTeX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply miss the closing brace `}` at the end of `\text{if`. Afterwards, you can quit the textmode before `x > 0` to typeset `x` in math mode.

You have finally :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[ f(x) =
    \begin{cases}
    x  & \quad \text{if } x > 0\\
        0  & \quad \text{else}
        \end{cases}
        \]
\end{document}
```

with the corresponding output :
[image]

Comment: the missing brace it's because I did a bad copy of the code, but the package amsmath resolve it, thanks!